# How to make element appear on scroll with vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I've a problem with my vuejs app (nuxt 2.15) : I make my elements appear on scroll with a class `.appear` that I add "manually" with this method (bind to a scroll event) :

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.part > *:not(.appear)').forEach(element => {
            const posTop = rect(element).top
            const trigger = window.innerHeight * 0.8
            if (posTop < trigger) {
                element.classList.add('appear')
            }
 })
```

This part work but the problem is that sometimes when a component re-render the class `.appear` is deleted by vue. How can i fix that issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the re-render will clear those attributes we added via DOM API. So for most of the time we will try not to use DOM API when working with frontend frameworks like Vue.

There's this [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) that can help us check if an element has been scrolled into the viewport or not. With this functionality, we can add a state like `isSeen` in `data()`, and use that state to determine what classes we should show in `<template>`.

You can check this [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqlVE2P0zAQ/SujCKldsU1aIS6h7YLgACckOBKE3GTSejexLXu6H6ry3xk7dht2JYRED5E9M+/Nxxv3lH0wJr8/YlZma8LedIJwWymA9WG1/Yxdp6/hQduuWRdsCI6P+qgILRT/eV0Xk4R8dbWVhqATar+pMnJVBg7paNgre6MtQUK3Vvcwy4t49/XPPN/IsM2usxGw6IXJb51W3N3J56+ig7lLCBZvY7i/V9mByLiyKFxbe85bl2u7L/iUW04ke8zR9Yud1Q+Os94yy/WEo2DjPdqFRdWgRfs3zmehL3g97VCpgVuZNPlMpIrWjbwHiy3Pq9aKhFQ+LdSdcC7YApQtZTKdYCaMQWFnJUj3HVFxniyIA2m+PJoTRCwMXIb3rXdHIq3gfd3J+u5C/vr1GQ7wRdUWe1QUMcUIGrUvuNh/kp3t+BgEb7AVx45GqZTosYRZLHIWRt8IEvOrJKXldbEq3SD1UMIy6gSx5xJa0TmM1tDhEC59QDQjZUUV8Vgdgd6NgsEGFD5wm8zqsCap1dfoms+5bSvRXcFmOy3B408gJ5Bvgr8wMFmE/Fj+hJsbOMVRc5UtzF8itrA8t+p/qaq8kY7zKI6dX13cdJAujxpvgCxvefTFPEMMHr+p0vMihQoDySteMTdG+crOEZNqzrXEwyRoMuSUK7D+mkw1HS9K7LDVFj+hI6ufLhL/iXzRuX8zk3+CccHoqUPgOINN2MQ87Xbk3GnLr7CElXkEpzvZwK4T9d270XtAuT9QCW+WS/MYbdqIWtITL1Y09MLupVrsNK97z0z8CoIndJ2PLy6lO4NXEUxWKCe9zmVywip/6xIDt+Nb2GbDb4eT45M=) for a live example. I would recommend you to open the Inspector and see when will the `.appear` class be added to the container.

- Scroll down to see those `<Counter />` "show up" (well, they are already there at the very beginning, we're just adding classes on them)
- Click "Increment" to make `<Counter />` re-render, and see the `.appear` class is still there

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your example ! This works well but the issue is that i must add a data attribute to each components, is there a solution that works globally ? That can make all components appear without changing them ?

Comment: @timothee_durand you can always have a wrapper component.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't manage to come up with a way to do it globally without changing all of the components. In Vue 2 you can "inject" the `data()`, `mounted()`, and `beforeDestroy()` logic via [plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin), but due to the fact that we need to retrieve the container element in every component, it makes it almost impossible without modifying every single component.

Comment: Maybe @kissu's recommendation is the best. You can create a component, put the Intersection Observer logic in it, and replace the container element of target components with that custom component. So in the end I think we still have to modify every file, and try to make the process easier.

Comment: Ok thanks for all your answers ! I'll make a wrapper component !